# For a post with categories, what is faster: Several database calls or additional PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm designing a blog database. I want posts to belong to any number of categories, including none (i.e. number of categories = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...).

I understand that the common way to design such a database (e.g. in Wordpress), is to have one table for posts, one table for categories, and one table for relationships, thus:

```
table relationships
    column relationship id
    column post id
    column category id
```

But this means that to display a post, my script will have to make at least three database queries. This seems slow to me.

Which is why, in another blog, I had only one table for posts which included a varchar column for categories, in which I inserted a string with all the category names, which I parsed in PHP, thus

```
table posts
    column post id
    ... (many other columns)
    column categories
```

where column categories contained a string that might look like this:

```
apples,oranges,bananas
```

which I simply `explode()`ed in PHP.

**Please explain why I should avoid the second method (one table, explode).** There must be something wrong with it that I miss, because it is not commonly used in blog software.

---

Note:

There might still be a table listing categories, into which new categories are written when a post is created, and from which lists of categories are drawn to display them in, of example, the sidebar.

I expect there to be many more queries for posts than for posts-in-categories, which is why I don't worry much about querying the second database for posts from a certain category, which might be faster in the first database.

Comment: [How to use JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) to select from multiple tables at once.

Comment: @JimL Are you implying that a JOIN is as fast as a call to a single table and exploding in PHP? (Which is what my question is about: speed.)

Comment: It's hard to answer the speed part of the question as you don't include a query (or set of queries) of what you want to do. You will however quickly find yourself in the position where you want to `SELECT * FROM post WHERE category_id = ?`, if that id is a comma separated string in a column a JOIN will be much much faster. Relational databases (and their normalization standards) are like they are to achieve sensible data storage and fast lookup/compares.

Answer (score 0):

In second case you will get huge problems with finding post by some category.

For example, you write posts about programming languages and want to show all post about python, php, ruby, etc on separate pages ... but you can't write simple and quick request to database because you violates 1 normal form in your second database scheme.

[JimL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078488/jiml) has already mentioned `JOIN` which allows to make 1 request and get all needed information from standard many-to-many relationship scheme with link table `post2category`